# Why msg.sender has the address of the deployer (address isnt the caller)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, decentralized-applications

I'm currently developing on a simple Naming Service for the Ethereum Blockchain.
`msg.sender` has the address of the deployer from the contract and not from the caller.

```
    address public caller;

      constructor() {
      caller = msg.sender;
   }
```

Using `remix.ethereum.org` and `pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;` and deployed on the JavaScript VM (London).

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: In which function do you check `msg.sender`? Here, in the constructor, `msg.sender` is the address of the deployer. That makes sense, because the account that deploys the contract, executes the constructor.

Comment: How to make the constructor the caller? Or are there other ways todo that

Comment: @zerokamix What do you mean by "make the constructor the caller"? Constructor is a function that is executed only once - during the contract deployment... Do you want to assign the contract address to the `caller` variable? Or do you want the `caller` variable to always reflect the current `msg.sender`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now `caller` is going to be equal to the address that deployed the contract because that is what `msg.sender` will reference.  If you are trying to make `caller` be the contract address instead, then you need to do `caller = address(this);`.  `address(this)` is the actual contracts address.